# runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference (golang-gorm) for POST Request

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
//main.go
package main

import (
    "TestGoProject/src/Mappings"
    "TestGoProject/src/Models"
    _ "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    _ "net/http"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func main()  {
    initDb()
    Mappings.InitializeRoutes()

}

func initDb() {
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "root:helloworld@/testapp2?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")

    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Models.BookModel{})
}
```

```
//router.go
package Mappings

import (
    "TestGoProject/src/Controllers"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func InitializeRoutes()  {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/", Controllers.Index)
    router.POST("/createBook", Controllers.Create)
    _ = router.Run()
}
```

```
//BookController.go
package Controllers

import (
    "TestGoProject/src/Models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    "net/http"
)

var db = gorm.DB{}

func Index(c *gin.Context)  {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": http.StatusOK, "message": "Im here!"})
}

func Create(c *gin.Context)  {
    book := Models.BookModel{
        Title: c.PostForm("title"),
        Author: c.PostForm("author"),
    }

    db.Create(&book)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"status": http.StatusCreated, "message": "Book created successfully!", "bookId": book.ID})
}
```

```
//bookModel.go
package Models

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

type BookModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
}
```

so when I send POST request from Postman getting an error like this tried to solve many ways but didn't work. any help that would be great. TIA

```
2020/05/25 10:54:50 [Recovery] 2020/05/25 - 10:54:50 panic recovered:
POST /createBook HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:513 (0x102bd98)
        gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz))

[GIN] 2020/05/25-10:54:50|500|2.968348ms|::1|POST "/createBook"
```

Comment: Panics come with stack traces. Find the line of your code where you use a nil pointer.

Comment: Just a guess without a full stacktrace: your `Controllers.db` global doesn't seem to get initialized, it's a separate variable from your initialized `main.db`

Comment: Aside from your error: 1. Don't use relative imports. 2. Why do you have so many imports as `_`?  `import ( _ "net/http" )` doesn't make any sense (it should have no useful side effects from importing).

Comment: I found that somehow ID is getting always Null. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `db` variable is not set properly for handlers

Set `db` in `gin.Context`

```
func InitializeRoutes(db *gorm.DB) {
    router := gin.Default()
    // Provide db variable to controllers
    router.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("db", db)
        c.Next()
    })
    ...
}
```

Send db from main

```
Mappings.InitializeRoutes(db)
```

And get from context to use in handler

```
func Create(c *gin.Context) {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    ...
}
```

Working code in playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Bnk4WTIkY4D)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In your spare time try to read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers also